# Excel macro: replace entire worksheet with different values

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, charts

Is it possible to replace entire worksheet with different values at the click of a button through macro? There are no "replace X with Y" or any recognizable pattern, I'm trying to replace ALL values in the worksheet.

To put it simply, I have two charts with an identical layout, but completely different values in each chart. I want the user to be able to switch between different charts **while on the same worksheet**, and each time user switches charts, the graph would automatically update to that chart.

Comment: Is Scott's answer what you're looking to do? Your question is kind of ambiguous to me.

Comment: Graph automatically update to that chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This quick dirty little code will replace the values on the active sheet with those in the same cells from another sheet:

```
Sub xFory()
Dim ows As Worksheet
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim rng As String

Set ows = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your destination sheet
Set tws = Sheets("Sheet2") ' change to your data sheet

rng = "A1:G12" ' Change to your range address

ows.Range(rng).Value = tws.Range(rng).Value

End Sub
```

Edit: edited code a little.